# Showing explicitly that a cubic surface is unirational.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{R}}$ be a cubic surface defined by an equation in affine co-ordinates
$$
x^2+y^2=f(z),
$$
where $f$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ with three distinct real roots. It is not hard to see that $X$ is not rational, that is, not birationally equivalent to $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{R}}$, by showing that $X(\mathbb{R})$ has two connected components while $X(\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{R}})$ is connected.

But is $X$ unirational? That is, is there a generically finite dominant map 
$$
\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{R}} \dashrightarrow  X?
$$
How do we construct this map explicitly?

Comment: Something like `\dashrightarrow` ($\dashrightarrow$) should work, no? Maybe a little hard to see.

Comment: Damn! How would anyone think to use that term?

Comment: which term? Originally, a variety $X$ was called birational (over $k$) if there was an invertible map $\mathbb{P}^n_k\dashrightarrow X$ for some $n$ and unirational if the map $\mathbb{P}^n_k\dashrightarrow X$ just goes one way. Then, at some stage, the prefix `bi' got dropped from birational.

Comment: It seems that http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0005146.pdf answers your question.